# How to hover images in SharePoint webpart?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, html

I have a webpart in my SharePoint sub site. This webpart contains an image and that image is linked to another site.

Since the image looks so plain, I decided to make a little make over. I want to make the image a bit bigger by using hover.

Can someone help me on this?

Here's my code in SharePoint:

```
<a>
<img width="190" height="55" class="ms-rteImage-0 ms-rtePosition-4" alt="images.png" src="/sites/pub/SitePages/Home/images.png"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a custom class name for the element and assign the styles for the same.

```
<img width="190" height="55" class="item ms-rteImage-0 ms-rtePosition-4" alt="images.png" src="/sites/pub/SitePages/Home/images.png"/>
```

```
.item img 
{
 max-width: 100%;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
 transition: all 0.3s;
 width:190px;
 height:55px;
}
.item:hover img 
{
 -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
 transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your reply. i am having a hard time embedding the code. Beliw is my current code in the SP site - auto generated.

Comment: <a> <h1 style="text-align: center;"> <span style="font-size: 15pt;">For New Mass Upload Request</span></h1> <p style="text-align: center;">Please click the button below.</p> <p style="text-align: center;"> <a href="/sites/pub/mdmrequests/Lists/New%20Mass%20Upload%20Req‌​uests/Item/newifs.as‌​px> <img width="190" height="55" class="ms-rteImage-0 ms-rtePosition-4" alt="images.png" src="/sites/pub/mdmrequests/requesttypeselection/SiteAssets/‌​SitePages/Home/image‌​s.png"/></a>&#160;</‌​p> <p style="text-align: center;">&#160;</p> </a>

Comment: Hi! code above doesnt seem to be accepted by my SP :(

Comment: whats the issue that you are facing?

Comment: I added the code as well as the class but it doesnt seem to work. Above is my whole code in the SP Site.

Answer (score 0):

Change your image tag as below:

```
<img width="190" height="55" class="thumbnail ms-rteImage-0 ms-rtePosition-4" alt="images.png" src="/sites/pub/SitePages/Home/images.png"/>
```

And add following css to page:

```
.thumbnail:hover {
    position:relative;
    top:-25px;
    left:-35px;
    width:500px;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
    z-index:999;
}
```

This will enable you to enlarge image on hower. Click [here](http://1.innovation.cloudappsportal.com/SitePages/howerimage.aspx) to view the demo.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your response on this but i cant seem to make the code work. This is my code in SP - auto generated by the sharepoint site

Comment: <a> <h1 style="text-align: center;"> 
   <span style="font-size: 15pt;">For New Mass Upload Request</span></h1>
<p style="text-align: center;">Please click the button below.</p>
<p style="text-align: center;"> 
   
   <a href="/sites/pub/mdmrequests/Lists/New%20Mass%20Upload%20Requests/Item/newifs.aspx>
   
   
   <img width="190" height="55" class="ms-rteImage-0 ms-rtePosition-4" 
alt="images.png" src="/sites/pub/mdmrequests/requesttypeselection/SiteAssets/SitePages/Home/images.png"/></a>&#160;</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">&#160;</p> </a>